# Click Replaces One Div With Another

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uc07as1/1/) you can see my html code.
You can see that all content on the right side is visible, I want to replace the div on click so when user clicks **car link** on the left side div with **cars is visible on the right side** and so on and so on with other links. I can't only replace the text because content will be generated by backend and there will be some logic with those divs

```css
.grid-container-order {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.4fr 1.1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "leftOrderCol rightOrderCol";
  width: 60vw;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.leftOrderCol {
  grid-area: leftOrderCol;
}

.rightOrderCol {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  grid-area: rightOrderCol;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.listOrderNavMobile {
  display: none;
}

.lineOrderPC {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  margin-top: 1vh;
}

.listOrderWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.userWelcomeOrderPC {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  padding-left: 1vw;
}

.userNamePC {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.linkOrderPC {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.linkOrderPC:hover {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.iconOrderPC {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  .listOrderNavPC {
    display: none;
  }
  .listOrderNavMobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .categoryRootMobileOrder {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    --gutter: 10px;
  }
  .hsOrder {
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 10px repeat(3, calc(35% - var(--gutter) * 2)) 10px;
  }
  .userWelcomeOrderMobile {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .userNameMobile {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 21px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container-order">
  <div class="leftOrderCol">
    <div class="listOrderWrapper">
      <div class="listOrderNavPC">

        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">Cars</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">Houses</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">boats</span>
        </a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightOrderCol">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Car">
        <div class="divCarsStyle">
          Mercedes
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Houses">
        <div class="divHousesStyle">
          Mansion
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Boats">
        <div class="divBoatsStyle">
          Boats
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: I've tried some js/jq from other similar topics but code was old messy and not working that's why we are here

Comment: Post your attempt please. Otherwise it looks like you're asking us to write everything for you, rather than help us figure out the problem with what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the text and the IDs matched

If you cannot change the text, we can use a data-attribute

I added css

```
.categoryInfoWrapper { display: none; }
```

```js
$(".listOrderNavPC a").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(".categoryInfoWrapper").hide();
  $("#"+$(this).find(".textOrderPC").text()).show();
})
```

```css
.grid-container-order {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.4fr 1.1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "leftOrderCol rightOrderCol";
  width: 60vw;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.leftOrderCol {
  grid-area: leftOrderCol;
}

.rightOrderCol {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  grid-area: rightOrderCol;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.listOrderNavMobile {
  display: none;
}

.lineOrderPC {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  margin-top: 1vh;
}

.listOrderWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.userWelcomeOrderPC {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  padding-left: 1vw;
}

.userNamePC {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.linkOrderPC {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.linkOrderPC:hover {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.iconOrderPC {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  .listOrderNavPC {
    display: none;
  }
  .listOrderNavMobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .categoryRootMobileOrder {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    --gutter: 10px;
  }
  .hsOrder {
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 10px repeat(3, calc(35% - var(--gutter) * 2)) 10px;
  }
  .userWelcomeOrderMobile {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .userNameMobile {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 21px;
  }
}

.categoryInfoWrapper { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container-order">
  <div class="leftOrderCol">
    <div class="listOrderWrapper">
      <div class="listOrderNavPC">

        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">Cars</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">Houses</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="linkOrderPC">
          <span class="iconOrderPC"></span>
          <span class="textOrderPC">Boats</span>
        </a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightOrderCol">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Cars">
        <div class="divCarsStyle">
          Mercedes
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Houses">
        <div class="divHousesStyle">
          Mansion
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryInfoWrapper" id="Boats">
        <div class="divBoatsStyle">
          Boats
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's running great but can only one be active at the time?, like cars are visible from the start and then user clicks houses cars become hidden and only houses are visible.